# understanding jquery ui events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The following is an excerpt from jQuery documentation

```
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the selected event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).selectable({
   selected: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
Bind to the selected event by type: selected.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "selected", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

I tried writing the following:

```
$("#somedivtag").selectable(); 
$("#somedivtag").bind("selected", function(event, ui) {
                  alert('something was selected');
                  return;  });
```

but the alert does not show up.

I don't think I actually understand the difference between supplying a callback and binding.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: If I write this it works:

$("#itemDetailsBody").selectable({
      selected: function(event, ui) { alert('you!'); }
  });

I don't know why the binding does not work, it would be good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the documentation is wrong, try adding "selectable" in front of the bind events (if they don't have one):

```
$("#somedivtag").selectable(); 
$("#somedivtag").bind("selectableselected", function(event, ui) {
 alert('something was selected');
 return;
});
```

Here is a complete list of the jQuery UI Selectable events:

```
selectableselected
selectableselecting
selectablestart
selectablestop
selectableunselected
selectableunselecting
```

---

I also wanted to mention that custom widgets will also have a different triggered event name... For example, the autocomplete widget has a ["catcomplete" example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) which starts with this code:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, { /**/ }
```

The events triggered by the custom widget will start with "catcomplete" and not "autocomplete". [This example](https://jsbin.com/jatulop/edit?html,console,output) binds to the custom widget "select" event:

```
$( "#search" ).on('catcompleteselect', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type);
});
```

Comment: yes, i received a reply from a forum indicating that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.bind will help you bind the event post-creation. If you know what function you want to be applied at the time of creation, you should use the option declaration, in my opinion.

I hope this helps: http://jsbin.com/olofi3/

**Update**

Sorry for the broken link. I'm not sure why, but JS Bin is just not working for me anymore. The code that I had tried to link you to was roughly:

```
$("img").selectable({
  stop: function(event, ui) { alert('something was selected') }
});
```

​
**Update's Update**

Apparently, it's just my Chrome that's not playing well with JS Bin. Oh well, the original link has been updated and replaced. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: i don't see any options that would do this, also the link you provided did not work.

Answer (score -1):

In second example - first row will do nothing, and as for the second - there is no `selected` event in `$("#somedivtag")`. Selectable is a function and it gets delegate as param and then raise that function on some internal event.

Comment: do you have an example as to how to bind the selected event?